# What does the merge parameter of a token do?

Tags: ace-editor

In the [ACE overview on creating syntax highlighters](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter&api=edit_session), under the section 'Defining States', the token definitions include the parameter `merge: true`. But I cannot find an explanation of what this does. What is its purpose?

Excerpt from example:

```js
this.$rules = {
    "start" : [ {
        token : "text",
        merge : true,
        regex : "<\\!\\[CDATA\\[",
        next : "cdata"
    },
    "cdata" : [ {
        token : "text",
        regex : "\\]\\]>",
        next : "start"
    }, {
        token : "text",
        merge : true,
        regex : "\\s+"
    }, {
        token : "text",
        merge : true,
        regex : ".+"
    } ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out by trial and error: Setting the `merge` property to `true` in a token will cause the token to be merged with the *following* token, both in the token list in memory and as a rendered `span` in the UI DOM, but only if the following token also evaluates to the same token type. I'm using this to merge the compound SQL tokens `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`:

In the following rules, the 3 tokens [`is` + (spaces) + `null`], or the 5 tokens [`is` + (spaces) + `not` + (spaces) + `null`] will be merged into a single token. If `is` is followed by something other that `not` or `null`, that something will be flagged as invalid. It will not be merged because, even though the previous token as still in `merge` mode, the resulting token class (`invalid`) for the next token is different.

```js
this.$rules = {
    "start": [{
        token : "keyword.operator",
        regex: "[iI][sS]\\b",
        merge: true,
        next: "is_keyword"
    }],
    "is_keyword": [
        {
            token: "keyword.operator",
            regex: "\\s+",
            merge: true
        }, {
            token: "keyword.operator",
            regex: "[nN][oO][tT]\\b",
            merge: true
        }, {
            token: "keyword.operator",
            regex: "[nN][uU][lL][lL]\\b",
            next: "start"
        }, {
            token: "invalid",
            regex: ".+",
            next: "start"
        }
    ]
};
```